# Python - Every other letter in a string capitalized within a loop where the data was handed down from a copied list of user input

Tags: python, list

I was instructed to have a user input at least 8 words into a list and then perform various manipulations to the data within the list. One of the manipulations it asks me to do is to create a loop that makes every other letter in the strings capitalized (hElLo WoRlD.) For better readability, I left out the other manipulations that I have done to the code.

```
import sys
def main():
    words = []
    wordCount = 0
    userWord = input("Enter at least 8 words or 'bye' to leave the program: ").split(' ')
    while True:
        if len(userWord)<8:
            print("Please print at least 8 words, try again.")
            sys.exit()
        elif wordCount >= 8 and userWord[wordCount] != 'bye':
            words.append(userWord[wordCount])
            wordCount = wordCount + 1
        else:
            break
     every_other (userWord)
def every_other(words):
    words6 = words.copy()
    st = ""
    for i in range(len(words6)):
        if (i%2) == 0:
            st += words6[i].upper()
        else:
            st += words6[i]
     print ('This is your list with every other letter capitalized: ', words6)
     return st
main()
```

I am not getting any error messages but the code doesn't seem to be running starting at def every_other.

Comment: It's breaking because - if you enter 8 words - in the first iteration of while loop - wordcount still will be 0, hence it will hit the last "else", which will break whole loop.

Comment: `words6.copy`? That's exactly what we had yesterday, right? So, is it just the next task in your homework? The function call was working yesterday - today, I see blank spaces...

Comment: `print ('This is your list with every other letter capitalized: ', words6)` located after `return st`

Comment: @nostradamus I promise I am not using Stack to do all of my homework. I am very new to Python and am getting hung up on things that I cannot figure out and that is why I am posting here. There are a list of about 15 manipulations total that I have to do to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to print the function `every_other` as it returns a string:

```
import sys
def main():
    words = []
    wordCount = 0
    userWord = input("Enter at least 8 words or 'bye' to leave the program: ").split(' ')
    while True:
        if len(userWord)<8:
            print("Please print at least 8 words, try again.")
            sys.exit()
        elif wordCount >= 8 and userWord[wordCount] != 'bye':
            words.append(userWord[wordCount])
            wordCount = wordCount + 1
        else:
            break
    print('This is your list with every other letter capitalized: ', every_other(userWord))
def every_other(words):
    words6 = words.copy()
    st = ""
    for i in range(len(words6)):
        if (i%2) == 0:
            st += words6[i].upper()
        else:
            st += words6[i]
    return st
    #print ('This is your list with every other letter capitalized: ', words6) # This will never run as the function has already returned
main()
```

If you want to capitalize every second character:

```
import sys
def main():
    words = []
    wordCount = 0
    userWord = input("Enter at least 8 words or 'bye' to leave the program: ").split(' ')
    while True:
        if len(userWord)<8:
            print("Please print at least 8 words, try again.")
            sys.exit()
        elif wordCount >= 8 and userWord[wordCount] != 'bye':
            words.append(userWord[wordCount])
            wordCount = wordCount + 1
        else:
            break

    print('This is your list with every other letter capitalized: ', every_other(userWord))


def every_other(words):
    st = ""
    new_st = ""
    for w in words:
        st+=w
    print(str(st))
    for count, val in enumerate(st):
        if (count % 2) == 0:
            val = val.upper()

        new_st+=val
    return new_st

main()
```

Comment: Exactly, just for clarification, @SSparks were trying to print after returning st, and then it wont be printed. 
And words6 is a list, so we are not iterating over the chars, but the words, so everyother word will be capitalized

Comment: I am very new to Python. The thing I am having the hardest time understanding in Python is the placement of things and how the program logically reads things. I don't know why it is causing me so many problems, but it is. Thank you both for your help! @Shadesfear, now that I am actually able to see it print, I see what you're talking about. Would that be how it worked for any list or is it just because of how I have it set up that it won't iterate over the individual characters?

Comment: When you iterate over a list, it will always iterate over each item in the list. Meaning that if each element is a string (or word if you will), your program will always just take it word for word. 
You have choices though, you can merge each element in the list, so it's just one long string, read .join. Or you can nest a for loop and iterate over each element in each word. 
Hope this helps

Comment: I've made a small addendum to my answer to help you further. Please see my edit for a solution that capitalizes every second character.